# ASP.NET MVC Razor: Dynamically build up HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to build up a link element () with several data-* elements in it (and an onclick-element) which are dynamically assigned / set depending on some variables of the model. So essentially the link might have no data-* elements up to X data-* elements in / on it (depending on the model state). How do I achieve this in a nice and clean fashion? Gathering pieces together with a StringBuilder and printing it out using Html.Raw(...) doesn't seem like a nice method to me.

One of the data-elements contain JSON-data. It would be great if the solution might include the way of encoding double quotes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think your first instinct is good. Just build everything you need on the back-end side. The biggest advantage is that you can write tests for that code and make sure what you do actually works for every scenario. It's a big win in my book.

have your code nicely separated into a class library, add everything you need to it. if you start on the code / html generation path you usually have more than one thing to build anyway.

Comment: I should have written my approach more precisely: In the view I was using a StringBuilder. I actually ended up with the approach to make an extension method for building the tag using a TagHelper which is very clean I think. The MergeAttribute-Method is very convinient. Also it would be testable as you mentioned, if your answer also refers to this approach.